# Mockito syntax for using When to stub return values Java Junit

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I have a Calculator interface:

```
public interface ICalculator {
public double evaluate(String expression);
}
```

I also have a View interface:

```
public interface IView {
public void appendAnswer(double anwer);
}
```

My Controller class has a method:

```
public void handle(String inputExpression) {
    view.appendAnswer(calculator.evaluate(inputExpression));
}
```

I'm trying to create a unit test for handle using Mockito.

```
private Controller controller;

@Mock
ICalculator calculator;
IView view;

@Before
public void setup() { 
    controller = new Controller();
    calculator = mock(ICalculator.class);
    view = mock(IView.class);

    controller.setCalculator(calculator);
    controller.setView(view);

//need a when here?
```

What I need to test for is that when the void method handle receives a String, the 
view.appendAnswer is called with a corresponding double argument.

```
@Test
public void testControllerHandleMethodCallsViewAppendAnswerMethodPassingADouble() {
    controller.handle("2.0");
    verify(view, times(1)).appendAnswer(2.0);
}
```

Fails with "Expected iView.appendAnswer(2.0), actual iView.appendAnswer(0.0)". 
Trying to find an answer has led me to believe I need a when clause in my setup() argument,
but I've been unable to figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mocked your calculator

```
calculator = mock(ICalculator.class);
```

All its method will return some default value, `null` for most reference types, `0` for numerical types, and `false` for `boolean`.

If you want these methods to return a pre-set value, you need to stub them. You can do that with `Mockito#when(Object)`.

```
Mockito.when(calculator.someMethod()).thenXyz()
```

*Xyz* depends on what you want to do. In this case, I assume you want

```
calculator.evaluate(inputExpression)
```

the evaluate method to return `2.0` when given any `String` value.

You can do that with

```
Mockito.when(calculator.evaluate(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn(2.0);
```

Alternatively, if you already know which `String` value you will pass, you can use that directly

```
String expression = ...;
Mockito.when(calculator.evaluate(expression)).thenReturn(2.0);
```

In this case, you can verify that `evaluate` was called with the right value

```
verify(calculator).evaluate(expression);
```

---

Based on your comments, you need an `Answer` more or less like

```
Mockito.when(calculator.evaluate(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Double>() {
    @Override
    public Double answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        String argument = invocation.getArgumentAt(0, String.class);
        Double returnValue = Double.parseDouble(argument);
        return returnValue;
    }
});
```

Comment: I was hoping to figure out a way to make mockito return the double corresponding to the String it was it passed, as in get thenReturn to return Double.parseDouble on the String. So if passed "3.0" it returns 3.0 etc, not just a hard coded 2.0. Is this possible?

Comment: @Saf How is it supposed to know? That is very custom behavior. You've created a mock. By definition, this is a stupid object that has no defined behavior.

Comment: yes you can using andAnswer() instead of andReturn() but agree with @SotiriosDelimanolis why reimplement the mocked behavior?

Comment: @Sotirios It looks possible using http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html but I couldn't manage to adapt the syntax and make it work

Comment: @Saf That is called stubbing. You define the mock to return some value. Similar to what `thenReturn(2.0);` does, except with more complex behavior.

Comment: @Arne I was hoping to setup the code so that any test taking a string argument would convert the string to a double and return that. So if I write another test for "3.0" it will pass using the same when / returnAnswer. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: @Saf No. It's not. You want help with that?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes please, if you wouldn't mind. I tried adapting the code from docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html but couldn't get anywhere with it.

Comment: @Saf I've added an example. But not that equality comparisons on `double` values is not always precise.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis bingo, almost. I had to edit it a bit. The override had to go, it made the compiler complain with a few weird errors, and the string assignment needed to be String argument = invocation.getArguments()[0].toString();
Thank you.

Comment: @Saf Which version of Mockito are you using? And which Java version? Neither of those changes should be required.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis javac is showing 1.8.0_40, java the same. Mockito is <version>1.9.5</version> in the projects POM file.

Comment: @Saf I'm on 1.10.19 Mockito.

Comment: @Saf not wrong, but there is no real dependency from the code. If the calculator returns the value twice, then 4.0 has to be passed to the view.

Answer (score 2):

First you should define the behavior of your mocks using when:

```
when(calculator.evaluate(anyString()))
  .thenReturn(2.0);
```

Then the unit to be tested should be called:

```
controller.handle("2.0");
```

Afterwards verify the mocks are called right:

```
verify(calculator).evaluate(eq("2.0"));
verify(view).appendAnswer(eq(2.0));
```

(Used many static imports from Mockito, btw: the @Mock annotation is not used)